# Can I use the Sitefinity Membership Provider for aspx pages that are included in my Sitefinity application

Tags: sitefinity

I would like to be able to add aspx pages to my sitefinity project and secure the pages using the Sitefinity Membership provider.  Specifically I will need to set the security level of pages in specific folders by adding allow and deny elements to the web.config.

```
<authorization>
   <allow roles="Admin, Customers"/> 
<deny users="*"/>
```

Is this possible out of the box? If not can anyone suggest an approach that might achieve the same/similar affect?

Answer (score 0):

One way I would approach this is to extract the logic of the aspx pages into user controls (ascx) and register them as widgets in Sitefinity.

Then create the page in Sitefinity and add the widget on it.

Finally, use the Permissions on the page level to determine who can do what.

Comment: Too time consuming, I have 200+ existing aspx pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a widget that works like this:

1. parse the url of the Sitefinity page being visited
2. [use the url parameters](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/how-do-i-construct-a-dynamic-page-url-in-sitefinity) to load the content for that url from the aspx
3. return the content to the visitor in Sitefinity

You could then create a single page for each group you want to control access for.

Oh, it's important to [let Sitefinity know that you've handled the dynamic URL](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/how-do-i-construct-a-dynamic-page-url-in-sitefinity#HlE1TsE3622pWP8AAERlJg) so it doesn't throw a 404.